# Elastic Beanstalk unable to install packages with postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to deploy my django web server by aws EB.
but when I refresh my eb by `eb deploy` it's not working.
In error, postresql part set in EB is wrong (in my guess), so I captured that part:

```
2020/05/24 12:29:49.626792 [ERROR] Error occurred during build: Yum does not have postgresql96-devel available for installation

2020/05/24 12:29:49.626815 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [PreBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: EbExtension build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details. 

2020/05/24 12:29:49.626820 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
```

i don't know my problem.
here is my `package.config`:

```
packages:
      yum:
        postgresql96-devel: []
        gettext-devel: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is no `postgresql96-devel`, assuming Amazon Linux 2 (AL2).

In the AL2, there is only `postgresql-devel` (9.2). However, if 9.2 is not suited, then you can install 9.6 using `amazon-linux-extras`

```
amazon-linux-extras install postgresql9.6
```

To execute that command in EB in an automated manner, you can run it as a  in [Commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) section of your `.ebextensions`:

> The commands run before the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted.

Comment: Bunch of thank you!
I fixed the error thanks to your feedback!
Thank you again.

Comment: thanks , bru ...